# Android open emailclient programmatically

Tags: android, button, gmail

Is it possible to open an emailclient such as gmail when I click a button in my app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open Gmail Compose when a button is clicked in Android App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935009/how-to-open-gmail-compose-when-a-button-is-clicked-in-android-app)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes. You can launch it via Intents.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ emailAddress });
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send email"));
```

Comment: does work mate.  this is the way i did it   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto", EMAIL_ADDRESS, null));

Answer (score 6):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto", EMAIL_ADDRESS, null));
```

up to date way of doing it

```
        i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, SUBJECT);
        i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, BODY);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send email"));
```

Comment: Fyi to anyone, I think the `Intent.createChooser(i, "Send email")` part is not necessary. It lets you customize the message. For the standard chooser/picker, you can simply call `startActivity(i)`

Answer (score 0):

If above code is not working then try this.
Tested and working

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/email"); 
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{Constants.FEEBBACK_EMAIL_ADDRESS});
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail using..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

This Worked fine for me

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"mobiz@gmail.com"} );
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback/Support: Speech to text App");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share "));
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply use below code when for no attachment:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:support@mailname.com")); 
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback/Support");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send feedback"));
```

For details I recommend to visit:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email