# How to open Only mail clients in Android

Tags: android

I refereed this answer [Android open emailclient programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596971/android-open-emailclient) programmatically in Stackoverflow to open the mail client, if i try this in my phone, its not showing Gmail or any other email client, instead its showing Skype, Bluetooth options. Kindly help me how to remove these options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a specific email address you are trying to let the user send a message to, use an `ACTION_SENDTO` `Intent` with   a `mailto:xxxx@yyy.com` `Uri` (where you replace `xxxx@yyy.com` with the actual email address).

Otherwise, what you want is not a good idea. Your users may wish to share their data via any number of mechanisms, some of which will not be email clients. [Please let the *users* choose how to share their data](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/28/share-where-the-user-wants.html).