# How to Open gmail,yahoo mail and rediff mails in application programmatically?

Tags: android, email, gmail, yahoo

I am working on an application which uses the mail viewer functionality and i want to view mail from gmail,yahoo mail and rediff mail. I am able to access from google with its uri and showing its mail in a webview created in my application.But i am unable to find any kind of uri or intent to open/access yahoo mail and rediff mail.I dont want to open their default mail application.I want to fetch them all and show them in my own application.Is there any way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

Here is yahoo developer api

http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/
http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/docs/user_guide/

and rediff api

http://developers.rediff.com/wiki/doku.php?id=table_of_contents

you might want to study K-9 mail code and get some idea's from there.

http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/