# Launch Yahoo Mail from another app

Tags: android, yahoo

The code below is used to launch Facebook:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

I trying to accomplish the same  for Yahoo Mail App.

Any idea what names need to be used in the Intent and setClassName statement?

Thanks

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935009/how-to-open-gmail-compose-when-a-button-is-clicked-in-android-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935009/how-to-open-gmail-compose-when-a-button-is-clicked-in-android-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve the `Intent` associated with launching an app:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager(); // from any Context
Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(
    "com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail");
```

This has the benefit of continuing to work even if they update the application to use a different main activity.

Comment: This is a good idea. I was just trying to answer the exact question. :)

Comment: Hannibal,What was your source for looking up the packageName:    "com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail"

Comment: @Richard - you can view the package name by looking at the id field in the [Google Play Store URL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail) for the app you want to open.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
intent.setClassName("com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail",
    "com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail.activity.MainActivity");
```

(The action is always the same).

You can read this information from the APK's manifest.

Comment: First get the apk (e.g. with http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/) then use apktool to decode it.

Comment: Matiash,  considering this app is not from Google Play, can it be trusted? Is it safe to use?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend installing it. But you can download and inspect it just fine.